# PowerPoint addin: Justify alignment in a text-box

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins, powerpoint-2013

### Explaining the problem

I am developing an addin in powerpoint and i am trying to create a textbox with justify alignment:

```
Shape newTextBox = currentSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(...);
TextRange boxTextRange = newTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange;
textRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = PpParagraphAlignment.ppAlignJustify;
```

The results are not as expected. When i type an 'enter' character in this box, the line is not justified. Why? Because with every 'enter' character, a 'paragraph' character is automatically inserted. Here is a screen shot of the copy-pasted text from the powepoint text-box to a word document:

[image]

In every case, the line is considered the last line of the paragraph and it is not justified.

However, if i try to do the same thing on the title textbox in the [default title layout slide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-slide-layouts-e214cb7e-7b62-419c-8f4d-4c1756990d5f), there are no 'paragraph' characters.

---

### Question time ...

Is there a way to stop these characters from being automatically entered in the text box? Maybe an option that i can set via code?

Comment: Hitting Enter marks the end of a paragraph in PPT (and Word), and the last line of a paragraph shouldn't be justified, so this is normal and expected behavior.  Text in title placeholders behaves a bit differently.  But what exactly is the problem/what is your question?

Comment: I wanted to achieve a 'Title placeholder' behavior in the text box. I could replace the text boxes with placeholders, but i cannot add as many 'Title placeholders' as i want.

Comment: I feel like this is not possible. If this is the case, an answer that says that is fully acceptable :)

Comment: What *specific* title placeholder to you want to achieve?

Comment: For example, the 'Title only' placeholder which can be found in the link i have provided in the question. I must say if the behavior i have described is normal, there is no great need to change it.